# Is it legal to feed the pigeons in Stockholm?

Tags: legal, stockholm

I have recently been in Stockholm and saw only a few pigeons in the city (as compared to other cities). I am wondering if there is any regulation related to feeding the pigeons or if it is simply frowned upon.

I caught a glimpse of a person feeding a few pigeons while a man that seems to be working for the police was watching. However, this did not happen on the sidewalks or in the street, so nobody seemed to bother.

[image: Pigeons in Stockholm]

I tried finding whether it is legal or not to feed the birds in Stockholm, but could not find anything in English.

**Question:** Is it legal to feed the pigeons in Stockholm?

Comment: Yes it's legal. Why would you feed pigeons though? Pigeons are rats with wings.

Comment: @dan-klasson - I do not like feeding pigeons because they are very messy and I really like clean cities. I was just curious.

Comment: Maybe you haven't seen many pigeons in the very center of the city but in some bus stops you can't event tell how many pigeons there are as they're so, so many pooing everyhere. That was the case in the bus stop of Akalla where I used to take the bus to reach the Uni during my year of studies abroad.

Comment: There is [an alternative](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhuMLpdnOjY), though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it is legal to feed pigeons in Sweden.

However, it is not legal to throw things other than chewing gum, cigarettes and snus on the ground. So you can't just empty a 100 liter bag of bread on the street.

Also, some places like cafés and restaurants ask the guests not to feed the birds. One should follow these instructions as some of these signs actually are supported by law and violations could result in an arrest.

Feeding pigeons is something you usually do at parks or water parks (when feeding ducks).

It is not legal to poison, hurt or kill birds in Sweden without special permission - you could end up in prison.

---

*I'm a swede and used to be a politician. Municipalities can decide these kind of things.*

Comment: Do you mean to imply it _is_ legal to throw chewing gum, cigarettes and snus on the ground?

Comment: It is illegal to litter outdoors in public places. In 2011 the law was amended to allow the police to fine offenders. At that time the Prosecutor-General advised that a dropped cigarette butt, candy wrapper or bus ticket would be a minor infraction not qualifying for a fine. Still illegal. No loophole.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is legal. I have been living here and we do it with my children in the park  all the times.

Comment: This is an evidence that if it is illegal, the law is not actively enforced. How do you know that it is actually legal?

Comment: Police man often see us and do nothing, not even say a thing

Comment: I have seen people jaywalking in plain view of police many times, sometimes even in fairly reckless circumstances, and they were not cited. It does not make jaywalking legal.

Comment: @BorisBukh dangerous example, since sometimes [that's not illegal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116796/jaywalking-in-england).

Answer (score -1):

It is illegal to feed birds in Sweden. They put varning in My apartment door that it is not allwoed to feed birds infront apartment and street. And whenever i feed there is Always sonen People warning me not to feed

Comment: I never meet hating bird society like in sweden in all Europe

Comment: There are also 'do not feed the birds' warnings in the building I live in the Netherlands, with an explanation, bird feed is often the cause rats come. And there are many birds being a problem for health. It is not out of hate for birds.

Comment: What does this warning say? Does it have legal force? I see lots of warnings in buildings saying things like "close the door" but this is not the law.